# Не получается связать событие и кнопку

Tags: c#, xaml

Добавил кнопки в приложение не получается выполнить commandbinding?

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
namespace WPF.Commands
{
   public class DataCommands
    {
        public static RoutedCommand Delete { get; set; }
        public static RoutedCommand Edit { get; set; }
        static DataCommands()
        {
            InputGestureCollection inputs = new InputGestureCollection();
            inputs.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.E, ModifierKeys.Control, "Ctrl+E"));
            Edit = new RoutedCommand("Edit", typeof(DataCommands), inputs);
            inputs = new InputGestureCollection();
            inputs.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.D, ModifierKeys.Control, "Ctrl+D"));
            Delete = new RoutedCommand("Delete", typeof(DataCommands), inputs);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот код страницы куда пытаюсь добавить:

```
<Page x:Class="WPF.PageEmployee"

      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:command="clr-namespace:WPF.Commands"


      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="PageEmployee">
      <Page.CommandBindings>
<CommandBinding Command="Edit" 
           Executed="EditCommandBinding_Executed" 
                    CanExecute="EditCommandBinding_CanExecute" />

</Page.CommandBindings>
    <StackPanel Margin="3" Background="{StaticResource BackgroundWindowResource}">
        <Menu>

            <MenuItem Header="Действие" >
                <MenuItem Header="Отменить" ></MenuItem>
                <Separator></Separator>
                <MenuItem Header="Создать" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Редактировать" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Сохранить" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Найти" />
                <Separator></Separator>
                <MenuItem Header="Удалить" ></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Отчет"></MenuItem>

        </Menu>

        <ToolBar Name="ToolBar1" Margin="3">
            <Button Name="Undo" ToolTip="Отменить редактирование/создание" 
Margin="5,2,5,2">
                <Image Source="Images/Undo.png" />



            </Button>
            <Button Name="Save" ToolTip="Сохранить" 
Margin="5,2,5,2">
                <Image Source="Images/Save.png" />
            </Button>
            <Button Name="Find" ToolTip="Найти" 
Margin="5,2,5,2">
                <Image Source="Images/Find.png" />
            </Button>
            <Button Name="Edit" ToolTip="Редактировать" 
Margin="5,2,5,2">
                <Image Source="Images/Edit.png" />
            </Button>
            <Button Name="Delete" ToolTip="Удалить" 
                    Margin="5,2,5,2">
                <Image Source="Images/Delete.png" />
            </Button>
            <Button Name="Add" ToolTip="Создать" 
Margin="5,2,5,2">
                <Image Source="Images/Add.png" />
            </Button>
        </ToolBar>
        <TextBlock Margin="5" >Список сотрудников</TextBlock>
        <DataGrid Name="DataGridEmployee" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Фамилия"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Отчество"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Должность" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Дата рождения" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Телефон"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Электронная почта"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>

    </StackPanel>

</Page>
```

Comment: А вы не могли бы выкинуть всё ненужное из кода? Вот например `<TextBlock Margin="5" >Список сотрудников</TextBlock>` явно не нужен. Как и `DataGrid`.

Comment: А зачем меня интересует почему не срабатывает commandbinding

Comment: Чем меньше у вас кода, тем больше вероятность, что квалифицированному участнику захочется потратить своё время и разобраться в вашей проблеме. ([mcve])

Comment: Я ни кого не заставляю!

Answer (score 1):

Собственно а где связь между DataCommands и вашим Page? Я контекста у Page-а не вижу, да и класс вообще статический, не слишком хорошо это, хотя и допустимо. И где биндинги? Вот [тут](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/llobo/2009/10/29/new-wpf-features-keygesture-binding/) хороший пример есть, как надо соединять.

Comment: Пытаюсь этот пример выполнить http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/690/546/lecture/12357?page=4